# cordova requirements are not satisfied. "Android SDK Not Found"

Tags: android, cordova

i am using cordova version 6.5.0.

after following the instructions on [cordova site](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html) , i have wrote those commands in the CLI

```
cordova create myApp com.myCompany.myApp myApp
cd myApp
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-camera --save
cordova platform add android --save
cordova requirements android
```

i get this error:

[image]

i have installed android studio on its default location.

```
C:\Users\Liran\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
```

i have the sdk tools installed as it is shows in sdk manager.[image]

what else can i check to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Setup the Environment Variables at control Panel, selecting Advanced system settings, and clicking Environment Variables.

Then add the **ANDROID_HOME** variable with the value:

- C:\Users\Liran\AppData\Local\Android\sdk

Then setup in the variable path in your Environment variables in the end something like the next line, add first semicolon

- [[text in path];%ANDROID_HOME%;

Check this link: https://spring.io/guides/gs/android/#android-dev-env

Comment: i have done the steps as mentioned in the guide, but no help. the android studio itself is executing successfully the sample program